# pass std::type_index as template parameter to function template

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following code (which works fine):

```
namespace fruit {
   struct apple{};
}

namespace language{
   struct english{};
}

typedef std::pair<std::string, std::type_index> myPairType;

std::unordered_map<std::string, myPairType> myMap =
{
    {"paul", {"likes", std::type_index(typeid(fruit::apple))} },
    {"jonas",  {"likes", std::type_index(typeid(language::english))} }
};
```

Now I have the following function template:

```
template <typename T>
void GenerateProfile(void* data) {
    T* data_casted = reinterpret_cast<T*>(data);
     //the data are then set to some database
}
```

How can I pass `fruit::apple` or `language::english` as template parameter when calling my GenerateProfile function?

```
myPairType myPair = myMap.at("paul");  //This works fine
fruit::apple* ptr = nullptr; //or fruit::apple* ptr = ...
GenerateProfile<?>(ptr); 

//GenerateProfile<myPair.second>(ptr) is not compiling

//GenerateProfile<fruit::apple>(ptr) this one compile but I want to acess fruit::apple from myPair
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::type_index` stores type information **at run-time**. Templates are a **compile-time** construct. Therefore you need a way of converting from the run-time world to the compile-time one: a chain of `if`/`else` statements works.

```
if(myPair.second == std::type_index(typeid(fruit::apple)))
{
    GenerateProfile<fruit::apple>(...);
}
else if(myPair.second == std::type_index(typeid(language::english)))
{
    GenerateProfile<language::english>(...);
}
```

This can obviously be generated for you using *template metaprogramming*.

However, your approach is a code smell - do you actually need the type information at run-time? You might want to reconsider your design.

Comment: GenerateProfile<fruit::apple>(...);   I dont want to acess fruit::apple like this. I want to acess it from myPair. something like GenerateProfile<myPair.second>(ptr). But considering your answer it seems not to be possible right? since template need the typename at compile-time whereas this type is sored by std::type_index at runtime. true?

Comment: @Gaetan: correct. You might want to have a compile-time map, if your design allows you to.